# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for localStorage & JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, storage, onload

I am working on creating this website and my Javascript is having issues.
I'm getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
This occurs with one of my lines on my Javascript.

```
    var temp=localStorage.getItem(volunteerOpp);
         newObject = JSON.parse(temp);
              display newObject[0];
```

It is showing this error on line 3, I think and I'm unsure what the problem is.

Comment: what does "display newObject[0];" mean?

Comment: "display newObject[0];" is incorrect entry

Comment: Shouldn't it be `display(newObject[0])`? What is `display`?

Comment: Also, "newObject" is created as global variable, it was planned?

Answer (score 0):

That's the error JSON.parse throws when you don't feed it nice json. Have a close look at volunteerOpp for syntax errors, perhaps a property name not in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but you can try this:

```
var temp = localStorage.getItem(volunteerOpp),
    newObject = JSON.parse(temp);

console.log(temp);
console.log(newObject);
console.log(newObject[0]);
```

Comment: It's because JSON.parse(temp) returned null, are you sure that "temp" is correct?

Comment: I changed my answer a little, check "temp" and "newObject" variables, they're okay?

Comment: It means that "newObject" variable is null. "newObject" is null because "temp" is null. "temp" is null because you don't have "volunteerOpp" variable in your local storage